How should I optimize these multiple || and && conditions?
How to optimize the below condition in java? We are setting authorized to true or false based on the nested or, and statements, and their membership type.
public class ClassA {

    enum status {premium, member};
    boolean authorized;

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorized;
    }

    public void setAuthorized(boolean authorized) {
        this.authorized = authorized;
    }

    public void checkOut (double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
           authorized = (Status == status.premium) && ((cart <= 5_000.00) || (creditRating > 650)) ||
                        (Status == status.member)  &&  (cart > 5_000.00   ||  creditRating <= 650) ||
                        (Status == status.premium  &&   cart > 5_000.00   &&  creditRating <= 650);
    }
}


Status == status.premium || cart > 5_000.00 || creditRating <= 650 should be equivalent, assuming that enum isn't going to grow.

status Status should be Status status

@shmosel nope, the naming convention is weirdly inverted here: status is a type and Status is a variable name...

@STerliakov Exactly

Yes it is; and I need to test the and code after optimizing it. Not able to optimize this code block.

What are you optimising for? Performance, readability, maintainability... ?

what do you want to optimize for? Readability? 1) follow the Java Naming Convention (as already commented); 2) divide your expression (variables or methods,) eventually using switch for [sS]tatus {strongly opinion-based}

I need to test with code after optimizing for readability. I have added the switch case but not able to test this condition using MCDC. How can I make this two as false? (Status == status.premium  &&   cart > 5_000.00   &&  creditRating <= 650); (Status == status.premium) && ((cart <= 5_000.00) || (creditRating > 650))

If you're using an update-to-date Java version you can use a switch expression:
public void checkOut (double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
    authorized = switch (Status) {
        case premium -> true; // the first and third conditions combined are always true
        case member -> cart > 5_000.00   ||  creditRating <= 650;
    };
}

Like putting the logic inside the enum like srr7 said, it will make sure that you'll never forgot to update the code if a new status is added.
Unlike putting the logic inside the enum, it keeps the enum cleaner if you need this logic only in one place.

Expanding on why the case for premium returns true.
The condition is the combination of the first and third. The initial condition is this (removing some unnecessary parentheses, adding some to make bindings clear):
(Status == status.premium && (cart <= 5_000.00 || creditRating > 650)) || (Status == status.premium && cart > 5_000.00 && creditRating <= 650)
By using the "distribute AND over OR" rule we can simplify it:
Status == status.premium && ((cart <= 5_000.00 || creditRating > 650) || (cart > 5_000.00 && creditRating <= 650))
If we apply De Morgan's law we can rewrite the second part:
Status == status.premium && (!(cart > 5_000.00 && creditRating <= 650) || (cart > 5_000.00 && creditRating <= 650)).
It's now pretty clear to see that this now has the form Status == status.premium && (!X || X), which is the same as Status == status.premium && true or simply Status == status.premium.

I need to test with code after optimizing for readability. I have added the switch case but not able to test this condition using MCDC. How can I make this two as false? (Status == status.premium  &&   cart > 5_000.00   &&  creditRating <= 650); (Status == status.premium) && ((cart <= 5_000.00) || (creditRating > 650))

@Sudharshan only by using status.member. I've added an explanation on why the part you copied is the same as Status == status.premium.

By using one of the oldest features of practically all programming languages: meaningful method names:
public void checkOut (double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
    authorized = isPremiumWithCreditRating(cart, creditRating, status)
         || isMemberWithoutCreditRating(cart, creditRating, status)
         || isPremiumWithoutCreditRating(cart, creditRating, status);
}

private boolean isPremiumWithCreditRating(double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
    return ...
}

private boolean isMemberWithoutCreditRating(double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
    return ...
}

private boolean isPremiumWithoutCreditRating(double cart, int creditRating, status Status) {
    return ...
}

(Or whichever method names suit your business logic.)
However you call them: make the code readable for a human being in your business context. This pays into maintainability, and that's all optimization you ever need.

I need to test with code after optimizing for readability. I have added the switch case but not able to test this condition using MCDC and boundary value conditions?. How can I make this two as false? (Status == status.premium  &&   cart > 5_000.00   &&  creditRating <= 650); (Status == status.premium) && ((cart <= 5_000.00) || (creditRating > 650)) 

I prefer to use enum and BiFucntion instead of checkOut method.
Suppose: In the future we will not have more changes in checkOutAlgo.
Also you can use a wrapper class if you have more arguments for checkoutAlgo.
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Test {

    enum Status {
        premium((cart, creditRating) -> (cart <= 5_000.00) || (creditRating > 650) || (cart > 5_000.00 && creditRating <= 650)),
        member((cart, creditRating) -> cart > 5_000.00 || creditRating <= 650),
        ;
        private final  BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Boolean>  checkOutAlgo;

        Status(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> checkOutAlgo) {
            this.checkOutAlgo = checkOutAlgo;
        }
    };

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check(Status.member, 10, 40);
    }
    
    public static boolean check(Status status , int cart , int creditCart) {
        return status.checkOutAlgo.apply(cart, creditCart);
    }
}




public class ClassA {

    enum Status { PREMIUM, MEMBER }    
    private boolean authorized;

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorized;
    }

    public void setAuthorized(boolean authorized) {
        this.authorized = authorized;
    }

    public void checkOut(double cart, int creditRating, Status status) {
        boolean isPremium = (status == Status.PREMIUM);
        boolean isMember = (status == Status.MEMBER);
        boolean lowCartValue = (cart <= 5_000.00);
        boolean highCartValue = (cart > 5_000.00);
        boolean goodCredit = (creditRating > 650);
        boolean poorCredit = (creditRating <= 650);

        authorized = (isPremium && (lowCartValue || goodCredit)) ||
                     (isMember && (highCartValue || poorCredit)) ||
                     (isPremium && highCartValue && poorCredit);
    }
}


so highCartValue is the same as !lowCartValue (unless developer changes one and forgets the other); similar for *Credit || by the way, code only answers are not preferred on StackOverflow

This is exactly what the question stated but without any lazy evaluation. I don't really see how that makes the code better.
